# mod rewrite - second rule is not working

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I am trying to learn url rewriting.

My code:

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule ^/$ /index.php
RewriteRule ^/([a-z]+)$ /index.php?page=$1
```

When I try it like this: `localhost/mysite` it shows home page. But when I try something like this: `localhost/mysite/abcdefg`, it would show a 404 error.

**EDIT**
What I want to do is:
If only original domain is given, it should goto home page. Eg: `www.mysite.com` --> `www.mysite.com/index.php`. Otherwise, if `www.mysite.com/contactus` --> `www.mysite.com/index.php?page=contactus`

**EDIT**
I am using WAMP server in Windows XP.

Comment: I see your edit, but you can't test that rewrite in the current URL structure you have in the localhost. You should try and setup virtual hosts to test in an environment that resembles your production as much as possible.

Comment: Can we add an additional condition that can be easily removed later. Means, if it is localhost, use `localhost/mysite/` otherwise just `www.mysite.com/` ?

Comment: Yes, you can. I am going to update my answer with a solution to this. However, lots of things would be better for you if you would use virtual hosts.

Comment: I have followed this tutorial: http://www.ruifeio.com/2011/01/30/setting-up-virtual-hosts-on-wampserver/

Now my WAMP server is not starting all services(still shows yellow icon instead of green). Let me try restarting the PC.

Comment: WAMP is good, but not as good as XAMPP in my opinion. Since, you have done some work, you may go forward with WAMP though.

Comment: ok. When uncomment this line:`# Virtual hosts``Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

in `httpd.conf` file and restarts WAMP, it would stay in yellow. But if I have commented it, WAMP will start fine(green).

Comment: It should be only `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` not `Virtual hosts``Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`.

Comment: Yeah. The first one was a comment. When I posted it here, it get concatenated into a single string. I was commenting and uncommenting the second line.

Comment: If the file is there, the daemon should start fine. Maybe you should take that discussion to WAMP forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>That's because the first rule would catch the second request.</strike> Now, that I took a closer look at the regex, no it would not catch the request. However, your second request would fail. Also, as a rule of thumb the more specialized a rewrite is the higher it should be placed.

You don't need to rewrite all the requests to index, but if you know what you are doing, then re-order the rewrites.

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/$ index.php [L]
```

---

**Edit 1**: Taking into account that you are working on a localhost, this would work for you.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mysite/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ mysite/index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^$ mysite/index.php [L]
```

When you go live, just remove the `mysite/` part.

*Note*: You don't need this rule `RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [L]` the server will automatically load `index.php` if you visit `localhost/mysite`. That is the expected behavior if your server is configured to load a default page, the file `index.php`, on `httpd.conf` configuration file.

---

**Edit 2**: I see your edit, but you can't test that rewrite in the current URL structure you have in the localhost. You should try and setup virtual hosts to test in an environment that resembles your production as much as possible. Search on Google for how to create virtual hosts for your WAMP, XAMPP, or any other stack you are using.

Then the rewrite rules are simple

```
RewriteEngine on
# page-url -> index.php?page=page-url
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: The first rule would NOT catch the second request. It's basically start-slash-end, which is not something that catches `/mysite/abcdefg`. The problem is the `/` isn't matched.

Comment: Ah, I see. But this I don't think the current regexp makes too much sense? I'm pre-coffee, but it looks like it only accepts 1 character that isn't a `/` ?

Comment: @Nanne I am pre-coffee too. That's why I forget those pluses and stars, we will get there eventually. Thanks for the help. :)
Edit: It still won't work, unless the op has set a `RewriteBase mysite`. It's not good to try rewrites in an environment that differs from the production.

Comment: But that didn't worked. It will load the default WAMP index page(localhost/index.php) even if I use (localhost/mysite/)

Comment: @VppMan You mean it didn't work before, that's why you needed the rule, or it doesn't work now?

Comment: When I turn off RewriteEngine(the rules used are yours), the site loads. But when I turn it ON and goes to `localhost/mysite`, it would load the default page of WAMP (which is same as `localhost`)

Comment: Maybe regex is matched correctly, but the redirection goes back to `localhost\index.php`

Comment: @VppMan Okay, fixed it. It's nasty, but it should be fixed.

Comment: I have setup the virtualhost by following this tut: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_IjEtqpD23I&feature=related

When I used your rules(with base as "/"), it shows a misconfiguration error(500)

Comment: Got it cleared. Solution: `RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]`. This seems to be the problem: `([^/]+)`. Error logs said: `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Comment: @VppMan Okay, seems like this issue has been resolved. Feel free to mark this question as answered by choosing any answer that helped you solve it.

Comment: Eventhough you have helped me, the real solution include creating virtual hosts too. So, can you make a new post with the answer to both virtual host creation and the regex solution. I will mark it as solution. Isn't it good choice ?

Comment: @VppMan I added the extra details on the second edit. That should do it.

Comment: Everybody around RewriteRule stuff forget the QSA directive. And if the user wants to access to "**`/test?p=aa&q=bb`**"? That's impossible because your rewrite rules remove the query string. Use "**`QSA`**" directive to keep it.

Comment: @OlivierPons Well, that's a matter of choice. If you want to account for certain parameters in the URL and you take care of those in the re-write you don't need to append the query string. On the other hand, if you also expect variable parameters, then, yes, you need to add the `QSA` directive.

Answer (score 0):

`/localhost/mysite/abcdefg` will not match the rule you expect it to match because the path (`/mysite/abcdefg`) contains a `/` in the middle that is not matched by your regular expression.  So the web server looks for the file, can't find it, and returns a 404.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-z]+)$ /index.php?page=$1
```

will match any string beginning with`/` followed by any number of characters `a-z`. `/` is not in that range, that is why it fails on `/mysite/abcdefg`.

Answer (score 0):

@trott and @anders_lindahl are right:

Your first only matches `localhost/` aka the root of the site.

The second rule will match anything that has lowercase letters (and just that!) after the first slash, so `localhost/thisisavalidstring`.

You have put a `/` in there, so it will not match. use something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-z\/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1
```

(haven't tried it, but I assume it will work. I'm not too sure about the need to escape inside the `[]`)

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to use

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-z/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-z/]*/)?([a-z]+)$ /index.php?page=$2
```